# Error while adding members to replica set

Tags: json, mongodb, replication

While adding members to replica set:
Error encountered:
errmsg" : "exception: need most members up to reconfigure, not ok
rs.status() gives

```
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2013-05-26T12:12:09Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "Bhavneet-PC:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 9286,
                        "optime" : {
                                "t" : 1369561487,
                                "i" : 1
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-26T09:44:47Z"),
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Recently I got the exactly similar error, when my 'keyFile' in other server ( which I was adding ) was not matching with the keyFile of rest of the replica cluster. You can check if this is not the case with you.

Comment: Version is 2.4.3 Please help really stuck here :(

Comment: I am confused, this has never happened to me before but ok, how did you initiate the replica set, have you (as @AbhishekKumar stated) checked the auth on the incoming secondary is working correctly?

Comment: @user1208710 : check the logs of the member you are adding, you will get to know about the connection that was tried to made, but failed because of which reason. I got to know the issue from the logs only.

Comment: Without a log snippet, it is incredibly hard to pin down what the root cause of this issue is. Can you `telnet SECONDARY 27017`?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have started all the mongod instances that you want to include as a replica with --replSet.  I resolved this issue by restarting the instances with said option.